# Handling queries with singular/plural feature in Solr

Tags: solr, stemming

I am trying to handle the singular/plural queries. Here is the text_general type schema

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Still the query results for "mobile" and "mobiles" are different.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory` for token filter.

Add this filter`<filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory" />` to your analyzer type="query" and check in analysis page.

"mobiles" will become "mobile"

same can be done for indexing.

Hope this helps